# Can you iteratively import python modules?

Tags: python, import, module

Say I have some python modules:

```
mymodule1.py
mymodule2.py
mymodule3.py
mymodule4.py
...
```

Can I iteratively import them?

This attempt doesn't work.

```
for x in range(1,5):
    mymod = 'mymodule' + repr(x)
    import mymod
```

Also, is there any reason why doing this is ill-advised?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `importlib`

A simple usage can be:

```
import importlib
mymodule = importlib.import_module("path/to/my/module.py")
```

Then you just have to adapt this code to import what you want "iteratively" (which I don't exactly know what it means).